# Is there a requirement for DHS CBP to provide a phone call for detainees claiming to be Americans?

Tags: customs-law

Francisco Erwin Galicia was stopped at US DHS-CBP checkpoint and held 23 days incommunicado in Texas.  If he made the claim that he was an American, are authorities required to provide him with a phone call?